# EventLoopScheduler equivalent in RxJava?

Tags: rx-java

Is there an RxJava equivalent for Rx.Net's `EventLoopScheduler`?

Looking through the documentation I think I could create my own Executor and use `Schedulers.from(Executor)` to create something similar, but I'm interested to know if there is an existing implementation or a better way to get `EventLoopScheduler` behaviour in RxJava.

Answer (score 2):

in a new version of rxJava (0.18.0) EventLoopScheduler was added : see in [changelog of 0.18.0](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/68a61e20d859b99504396c9743b3e6fc08e9d4c1/CHANGES.md)
in `rx.schedulers.EventLoopScheduler`

Comment: It's available via `Schedulers.computation()`